# How to create a coroutine scope tied to a loggedin user?

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, kotlin-coroutines, cancellation

Is there a way to create a CoroutineScope that is tied to the loggedIn user?

Basically, the idea is to create a coroutine scope, which I can cancel when the user logouts so that all the jobs being done on that scope gets cancelled.

My idea is to create a singleton class that holds a map between the userId and coroutineScope then inject the class wherever I need. Then I would observe the loggedInUser and cancel the scope that doesn't belong to the loggedInUser and then delete the scope.

Is this a good way or is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to rethink your design. You don't want to store multiple scopes that are tied to some specific IDs since it will force you to do extra work like cancelling and disposing scopes that are not used or refer to another ID.

Usually, coroutines and their scopes do not depend on authentication and authorization states. You better control these states on the backend or in your business logic layer if you don't have the backend.

For example, you perform the authentication and if it fails or is not performed at all you don't provide the user with any logic/functions that requires being logged in.
Otherwise, if it is performed, you pass the token/id/etc. to the following API calls, that will provide you with data that is relevant for current user.

You don't want to implement switching between coroutines that is dependent on the current user. Concurrency in your application should be structured and not very complicated. Availability of data or functionality should not depend on some coroutine scope.

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I wouldnt try such an implementation then. But I have a question..lets say.. I am in screen A.There is a button: "skip" that informs the server that no action has been taken. Also on click of this button, I would like to navigate to screen B and clear the backstack. So if I use viewModelScope of screen A to inform the server that skip has been clicked, there is a chance that this request is cancelled as viewModel is cleared. So should I :1) create a new scope to make this api req and never cancel the scope or 2) wait for the req to be completed before navigating to screen B

Comment: You probably want to delegate request sending to a service/repository, which will not be cleared/deleted even if the ViewModel will die

Comment: However it is a good practice to wait for request to complete or fail, since you usually want to notify user about an error or make sure the request completed before proceeding to further logic

Comment: so do I maintain my own custom coroutineScope in the repository for such operations?

Comment: Yes, it will also have context with IO dispatcher for API call purposes

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can accept it and we will close the question :)

Comment: So I was thinking of how to maintain a customScope and it got me thinking. Is it a good idea to inject a singleton coroutineScope with hilt in all the repositories?

Comment: I think it is fine, as soon as you will create child coroutines of the scope and use different Childs for different repositories, so one will not block the other

Comment: I was thinking of using supervisor job as the parent job for the scope. Then as the child coroutines are created, it defaults to a default job and I don't think there will be any problem. Are there any issues with this?

Comment: I suggest to read about the architecture parents that are using coroutines, Redux/MVI use something similar to what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you want to store user data like lists, object etc while user is logged in then best way to go is data store. It's an upgrade to shared preferences which was previously used.

In data store you can observe data changes as it is live data and we can collect it in activity or viewModel scope.

This also works great because its lifecycle aware so you dont have to worry about cancelling it manually as it get resume on screen resume and pause when it goes in background or in back stack.

[Here is a link learn more](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/all-about-preferences-datastore-cc7995679334)

Call api as follow

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        dataStoreGetUserData().firstOrNull {
        
            callApi()

            true
        }
    }
```

this way data from data store is only obtained one time and
will not be called everytime data changes

Comment: I am using datastore to store the logged in user's auth token and details. I want to create a coroutineScope that is tied to the user.
I can use viewModelScope to make requests that fetch data for the UI but there are certain api requests that need not be cancelled whenever viewModel is cleared such as sending a message, liking a post, or any interaction by the user that needs to be informed to the server.

Comment: I have updated my answer check it out for how to make api call while getting token from data store